# Insuring that 00/00/0000, 00:00, "", 0 or NULL stays NULL when inserting with pdo prepare

Tags: php

```
  $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO `wp_product` (" .
      " `SoldDate`, `NoImage`  " .
      ") VALUES (" .
      " %s, %s" .
      ") " .
      "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " .
      "`SoldDate` = VALUES(`SoldDate`), ".
      "`NoImage` = VALUES(`NoImage`), ".
      array(
        $car->SoldDate,
        !$car->PhotoList
      )
    )
  );
```

I have this code and it seems NULL values, "" or 0 values turns into 0000-00-00 00:00:00, how do you insure that this date is always NULL when we receive 0, NULL, ""? The code used to work, but now it always return 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for every product and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values `0`, `NULL`, and `""` are not equivalent, and you've been relying on *something* to do the type juggling for you. Was it PHP? WordPress? MySQL? Who knows? Maybe all three!

The problem is now the juggler is juggling slightly differently.

If you want a particular value, set a particular value.

`$car->SoldDate ?: null` will make sure that "false-ish" values always juggle to `null`.

eg:

```php
var_dump(
    0    ?: NULL,
    1    ?: NULL,
    ""   ?: NULL,
    "a"  ?: NULL,
    "0"  ?: NULL,
    NULL ?: NULL
);
```

Output:

```
NULL
int(1)
NULL
string(1) "a"
NULL
NULL
```